# German ZIP Code Areas (free or commercial)

Tags: xml, database, maps, geospatial, zipcode

Good day,

I am searching for a database which contains the coordinates of the german zip code areas. All databases I found yet contain only a single LON/LAT coordinate (something like the middle of the area). **But i need the full path to draw polygons**.

Is there any database, free or commercial, which contains these data? 
The programming is not the problem here, but i can't start without the required data...

Example for an application using such data: The map at http://www.pizza.de

Comment: Is this a general propose or do you know an specific thread over there?

Comment: I know that Teleatlas (now Tomtom) has those, but I'm not sure if you get them standalone or just with all other street data.

Answer (score 0):

Navteq and TomTom (and probably AND) will sell you that data. You could also look at OSM (open street map) they have quite an active DE community and so it is likely you might be able to find DE postal codes.